# merge two lists to a list of string in python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7

I'm looking for a way to merge 2 lists in a list of strings from merged value

My probleme is that i don't understand how to write it correctly, i have a list of merged value list, insteed of a list of merged value.

actually this is the code I have :

```
listA = ['1','2','3']
listB = ['100','200','300']
merge = zip(listA,listB)
print(merge)
#[('1', '100'), ('2', '200'), ('3', '300')]
```

I expect to have this result (a list of string) :

```
#['1-100', '2-200', '3-300']
```

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `str.format` in a list comprehension

**Ex:**

```
listA = ['1','2','3']
listB = ['100','200','300']
print(["{}-{}".format(*i) for i in zip(listA, listB)])
```

**Output:**

```
['1-100', '2-200', '3-300']
```